# Git : Pushing to a modified repository

Tags: git, version-control, github

I was working on a project that I had cloned from `gitHub`, but while I was making changes to my copy, someone already pushed changes to the remote repo.
 What should I do now ? How do I `push` my changes to the `remote` repo?

I am new to gitHub and git .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `git pull --rebase` to pull in the changes from the remote repo. Then you can push your changes to the remote repo, provided you do not get a merge conflict.